# How to use ionViewDidEnter in directives

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I am trying to create a directive where I animate a fab-button when the view is shown.
The animation works if it is inside ngOnInit, but due to ionic route strategy the animation doesn't work when I leave the page and go back. Putting it in ionViewDidEnter didn't work because I presume that ionViewDidEnter doesn't work inside the directive. So is there any approach I can take to solve this?

```
 <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
        <ion-fab-button mode="md" appAnimateFab>
          <ion-icon name="create" mode="md"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab>`
```

```
    @Directive({
      selector: 'ion-fab-button[appAnimateFab]'
    })
    export class AnimateFabDirective implements OnInit {

      constructor(
        private animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder,
        private element: ElementRef
      ) { }
      ngOnInit() {

      }

      ionViewDidEnter() {
        console.log(this.element);
        const factory = this.animationBuilder.build([
          style({transform: 'rotate(-45deg)'}),
          animate('5s ease-in', style({transform: 'rotate(0deg)'}))
        ]);
        const anim = factory.create(this.element.nativeElement);
        anim.play();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I got halfway through writing out a detailed reply yesterday when I realised that you were actually asking about directives and not custom components... so all my research was wrong haha.

Today I have had another look. The tutorials all seem to conveniently miss having a requirement to deal with pages changing backwards and forwards and just lean on `ngOnInit`.

After scratching my head for a bit I started to wonder how else it could be triggered and I'm thinking: what about the Intersection Observer API?

I really like the way Alligator.io explain things:

[Using the Intersection Observer API to Trigger Animations and Transitions](https://alligator.io/js/intersection-observer/)

Their example shows the animation being triggered every time you scroll down to view.

If you are flipping pages then it feels like it should trigger as coming into view, but I haven't tested this out with code.

For a more Ionic-focused example with Intersection Observer API, Josh has a tutorial:

[Animating List Items in Ionic with the Intersection Observer API | joshmorony - Learn Ionic & Build Mobile Apps with Web Tech](https://www.joshmorony.com/animating-list-items-in-ionic-with-intersection-observer-api/)

Maybe you can adapt this to use your animation code?